# Accessing properties of the root controller on a UINavigationController stack

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have a `UINavigationController` with root HomeViewController().  HomeViewController has a property named someString. I want to access someString from another view controller that has been pushed onto the navigation stack programmatically:

```
navigationController?.pushViewController(DetailViewController(), animated: true)
```

In the DetailViewController that wants to access someString I am doing this:

```
var homeViewController: HomeViewController!

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  let navController = self.navigationController!
  homeViewController = navController.viewControllers.first as? HomeViewController
}
```

And then to get the value of someString from within DetailViewController:

```
var stringFromRoot = homeViewController.someString
```

Is this the proper way to access properties of the root view controller in a UINavigationController? It does work in my testing, but if it has errors or drawbacks, or if there is a better way, I would like to know about that.

Comment: It the root controller doesn't change, this should work. Avoid force unwrapping though (`!`)

Comment: It's ok as a workaround, but as a design it's very fragile and "dirty" (since the dependency of DetailViewController on MainViewController is not expressed in any way; and what if MainViewController is no longer "first" in its navcontroller?). Consider passing the value to detail controller in the segue, or use a delegate pattern (pass HomeViewCOntroller to Detail as a protocol delegate representing the data you need). See a lot of other ideas here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers

Comment: @KirilS. I ended up taking your advice and learned to rewrite it with a delegate solution.  If you want to answer with an example of that, I will accept your answer.  Otherwise I will write that up and accept it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the only way I know of accessing the root view controller in a `UINavigationController`. You asked about drawbacks, so here is one:

You can change the navigation controller's view controller's on the fly with `setViewControllers(_:, animated:)` so it might not be a good long term strategy to assume that the root view controller will always be `HomeViewController`

It looks like you're using your navigation controller as a singleton to store and retrieve constants. Unless `someString` depends on some value in your navigation controller, it would be more maintainable to extract that out to some kind of `Constants` struct.

Comment: You're right, the example I posted does suggest it's using root controller as a constants store, and your response makes sense.  In the actual code, though, the data is a freshly polled CLLocation that the root has (and uses) and other views need, too.  I should have noted that, but my main concern was finding the right Apple/Swifty way to communicate between controllers.  Seems like Delegate/Protocol is the answer I needed, and is how I ended up going.

Comment: Gotcha, for that particular case, I've seen people build singleton wrappers on top of `CLLocationManager` and save the most recently `CLLocation` in a property. Then you can get the location from any controller

Answer (score 0):

self.navigationController!.viewControllers

This will give array of view controllers added into navigation stack you can loop over it and accesss any of ViewController property
From it.

Comment: Which is exactly what I did in my example.